# Is numbers.10:7 a picture of how the church shall be spared from "sound of alarm" or great tribulation?

Tags: rapture

Is numbers.10:7 a picture of how the church shall be spared from "sound of alarm" or great tribulation?
I mean I have heard that this is picture of the church being spared from the "sound of alarm" or great tribulation. 
Is this biblical interpretation or too far reaching conclusion? 
I mean there is a trump at the rapture, but is it the last trump when rapture happens and if this trumpet of numbers.10:5 & 7 is picture of the last trump at the rapture?

source:

[[Prophecy in the News with Pastor Gary Stearman, "Will the Church Go Through the Tribulation?"](http://www.itbn.org/index/detail/lib/Networks/sublib/Church+Channel/ec/xycWR2bTqi9gSg4dryXW6_Dnt4DHVPZa), 19:40-( after 19 min. and 40 sec.)]

For those interested for transcript made by myself by hand and computer: 
" ...turn to the numbers.10:3-4. I think it is such an important note to reiterate for the audience. It says verse 3: ' and when they shall blow with them, "that's the two trumps, " the assembly shall assemble themselves to thee at the door of the tabernacle of the congregation. And if they blow but with one trumpet, then the princes, which are heads of the thousands of Israel, shall gather themselves unto thee. " That's it. The gathering together - picture of the rapture.> There you go. >> Then it says in verse 5, " When ye blow an alarm. " Wait a minute, no, this is something else. This is different. " When ye blow an alarm, then the camps that lie on the east part shall go forward. When you blow an alarm the second time, then the camps that lie on the south side shall take their journey and they shall blow an alarm for their journeys. " Now it goes back to the last trump picture in verse 7, "But when the congregation is to be gathered together, ye shall blow, but ye shall not sound an alarm. " Verse 7's the key. It says look, if you hear the last trump, that's the gathering together. But if you hear more trumpets, the seven trumpets of Revelation, that's an alarm. It's not a good thing to hear those alarm trumpets. It will not be in the tribulation. It will be a good thing at the rapture. > Absolutely and the astonishing thing is it's all there if you put it together, and Doug has done this in remarkable ways. Let me just stop for a moment and I want to offer some additional reading material for you, as we always do right here on Prophecy in the News. We have a package that we're calling the Blessed Hope Package. I mentioned this book a moment ago - Will the Church God Through the Tribulation? And you've contributed much of what you've talked about today to this book. We're putting that together with this book called The Departure. A number of authors have put their fervent ideas about the rapture of the church, the pre-tribulation rapture of the church, into this book called The Departure. And finally we have David... well I would like to wrap up with the rapture. > Okay, me too. >> I mean the catching up. Gary, as you know, there's a lot of debate on this, and I have read the critics and I know you've heard from them too and we always do. The problem is look, you've got to just believe to book. I could go and you could go through here and we could show picture after picture after picture of a pre-tribulation rapture because God wants us to see it. People that go to Matthew chapter 24 are taking scripture out of context. They're appplaying what was given to the nation of Israel about the tribulation period and trying to apply it to us as the church. They've got no business doing that and the problem is they don't rightly divide the word of truth. And if you don't rightly divide the word of truth and you don't study the Bible dispensationally, you're going to be confused and you're going to be tossed to and fro with every wind of doctrine. > You know, somebody once told me that you see a woman book of Revelation chapter 12 giving birth to a man child, that's Israel, and all through the Bible you have this figure of a woman in travail. Jeremiah talks about it a lot, Jesus talked about it in Matthew 24. She's giving birth. I think we see that today, we see Israel in birth pains, right? >> Absolutely. >So that tells us something. What I would like to say is it tells us to keep looking up, which I always say. Doug Stauffer, it's been great having you here today, and I wish we had more time. >>Oh absolutely. I loved it...

In my opinion Doug identifies alarm trumptets of numbers.10:4 to trumpets of judgements during the great tribulation and that's why it is not good to to hear those alarm trumpets, but first trumpet of numbers.10:4 will be a good thing for those part of gathered for the rapture.

Comment: I see no reason at all to think Numbers 10:7 has anything to do with the end times.

Comment: The Silver trumpets (Numbers 10) has no connection with Rapture or Tribulation. The Year of Jubilee (Leviticus 25) is more related.

Comment: Videos are a bit of a problem with slow internet. Maybe you can give the words for us living in the jungles.

Comment: Thank you, but now I do not see a question. You have answered it already.

Comment: @gideon marx: question starts at the second line on the first paragraph. I gave an opinion which is my interpretation for this analysis of numbers.10, which I copied from the tv-program. But not in anyway I'm certain about my "answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

God makes it pretty clear in verse 2 what the trumpet commands are for:

> **Numbers 10:1-2 ESV** The Lord spoke to Moses, saying, “Make two silver trumpets. Of hammered work you shall make them, and you shall use them for summoning the congregation and for breaking camp."

Now, you ***could*** say that this passage (or any passage) has some sort of hidden meaning, like foreshadowing the end times, and who could really tell you that you're wrong? As long as you're not outright contradicting other scriptures then the hidden meaning you suggest may very well exist, however the burden of proof is on you to *prove* that hidden meaning exists if you want to impose this interpretation on anyone but yourself. That's known as allegorizing the bible and it can get pretty subjective and dodgy, especially when people create doctrine out of hidden meanings that can't necessarily be proven right or wrong.

But we can look at this passage in this light:

- There's nowhere else in scripture that refers to Numbers 10 as a foreshadowed event, whether implicitly or explicitly.
- There's no other event in scripture that truly mimics the command God is suggesting. There's trumpets in the last days, but that's the only relation and it's a fairly loose one.

So to answer your question "*Is this biblical interpretation or too far reaching conclusion?*", I would go with too far reaching conclusion as there's nothing in the rest of scriptures that indicates this is a foreshadowing.